# How to simulate a button click in C# with timer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know how to simulate a click of a button with timer. I want a   button to be pressed every 12 hours.

Comment: Do you have a button in your own application of which you have the source code? Or you want to click a button on a window belonging to an exterrnal program?

Comment: Also is this a desktop application or a asp.net website your code will be running in. If it is a website you will run in to problems with your app domain shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to your timer tick event to call button click event logic

```
btnSubmit_Click(null, null)
```

Hoping you wouldn't use args or sender inside the logic.  Better way is to write a common method which can be called by button click and timer tick.

Comment: As this question is tagged as [tag:asp.net], where would you propose to place this code? How would you intend to cope with the application pool being recycled or just not having the web application loaded?

Answer (score -1):

Just call the method that defined for button event into timer event method.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   button1_Click( sender, e);
 }
```

you also could put null for parameters.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button1_Click( null, null);
}
```

For more details please refer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: As this question is tagged as [tag:asp.net], where would you propose to place this code? How would you intend to cope with the application pool being recycled or just not having the web application loaded?

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this,

First of all set property of Timer Control - > Interval : 216000000 (as you need for 12 hours) 
also set timer control to enabled

Syntax :

```
private void <YourTimername>_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  <YourButtonName>_Click( null, null);
}
```

Examples :

```
private void AutoTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  btnAutoEvent_Click( null, null);
}
```

Hope this will helpful for your work.

Regards,

Sagar Rupani

Comment: As this question is tagged as [tag:asp.net], where would you propose to place this code? How would you intend to cope with the application pool being recycled or just not having the web application loaded?